# How do I emulate Intel Thread Director behaviour in Linux not supporting it yet?

Tags: linux, threads, intel

My 12th Gen Intel© Core™ i7-1260P (Alder Lake) has 4 performance cores + 4 threads and 8 efficiency cores.
If a multi threaded task is launched, it prefers fastest performance cores, then physical efficiency cores and finally threads. This is behaviour described in a [Tom's hardware article](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-thread-director-coming-to-linux-5-18) and it's fine for getting maximum performance from the CPU.
But the older (pre 5.18) kernel can't use efficiency cores correctly and runs background processes (like indexing files) also on performance cores - there's always some random activity on those even if the system is idle.
Is there a way to emulate Intel® Thread Director in directing these background tasks to efficiency cores and keeping performance cores for "real heavy" tasks like processing graphics etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes - using CPU sets. Create a set for efficiency cores and move all root processes to that set (background tasks won't run on performance cores anymore). Then create a set for performance cores and modify launchers of all programs that need the extra power to use this set.
My configuration for i7-1260P (0, 2, 4, 6 are performance cores, 1, 3, 5, 7 are threads and 8..15 are efficiency cores) looks like this (I use `cset` utility for creating and manipulating the sets):

```
# cset set --cpu=0-15 --set=all
# cset set --cpu=0-7 --set=perf
# cset set --cpu=8-15 --set=effi
```

The set named 'all' uses all cores and threads, 'perf' uses only performance cores+threads and 'effi' uses only efficiency cores. Feel free to create others sets like for physical performance cores only or a single core if needed.

```
# cset proc -m -f root -t effi
```

After starting the system, I move all processes to the 'effi' set - they now use efficiency cores only.

```
# chmod -R 777 /cpusets
```

This has to be set so that users could start their programs in requested CPU sets.

```
$ cset proc --set=perf --exec gimp
```

And this is an example on how a user can start Gimp and run it on performance cores. This way all desired launchers can be modified (e.g. in .local/share/applications in some systems) so that with running them from menu or even from mime types, the requested CPU cores are used.